# Is there a method to change a character on a spesific index of a string?

Tags: python

I am trying to create a function to swap first and last characters of a string. I know .replace method doesn't work with this. I am wondering if there is any method for this. I don't want to seperate and add all of them at return.

```
def front_back(str):
    if len(str) > 1:
        str = str.replace(str[0], str[-1] )
        str = str.replace(str[-1], str[0] )
        return str
    return str
```

Comment: Don't use `str` as a variable name.

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific function for this, but simple slicing does the job well enough:

```
str = str[-1] + str[1:-1] + str[0]
```

By the way, don't name your variable `str`, since this will shadow the built-in `str` type and lead to confusion at best, and bugs at worst.

Comment: Yeah, i guess i should just go with slicing. The problem wants me to use str, that's why i use it. Thank u for your answer and suggestion.